# Membership system in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

I'm going to use the membership system  in ASP.net, but need to change it in 2 ways.
The database which stores the users is Access, and I want to salt the password(etc) plus ask the user to enter details like links to their facebook pages etc which are stored in the database.

So how do I use access with the system?

And how can I change/add fields which are stored in the database (i know how to create them in the database btw, just how I get the membership system to ask for it and store it)

(I could make my own registration/user login system, except I don't know how to restrict access to pages, so how could I go about this?)

Links to tutorials/references would be great

Comment: Just curious about why you would use Access instead of SQL Server Express Edition?

Comment: I'm curious also. SQL Express is a superior database engine compared to Access. Is there a technical reason for this descision?

Comment: Firstly, I have used Access in my GCSE work for the past year and a half, so I'm somewhat used to it. And doesn't SQL cost money?

Comment: Not the Express edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Use SQL Server Express edition.  It's free, it's good, it works out of the box.
2) Check out the Profile providers for personalisation.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

Answer (score 4):

And another on how to  [write a custom membership provider](http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29256/1954?pf=true) for the Access Database.

Comment: +1 For the link. I'd still go with SQL Express as suggested by the others :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link explaining how to use Access:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx

As for storing extra user information. Asp.NET provides this via personalization.  Here are two links to get you going:

Video: http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-43.aspx
Article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163724.aspx

Answer (score 1):

one more...

[Membership Provider MSAccess](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121456/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010307-1.aspx)